# "Fair law" Is it used correctly here?

Tags: word-choice

I came across this expression in a book written by non-native speakers. The book will be used for 6th graders in Turkey.
Do you think the writers used the expression correctly here or do they mean something like "fair trial" and "natural justice"?
Is there really an expression like "fair law" to describe scales of justice?[image]

Comment: good questions ... but use of this forum to correct the AmE translations of foreign governments is likely off topic

Answer (score 1):

The term generally used to describe a system in which legal disputes are decided fairly and without undue influence from powerful people (such as the government) is "rule of law".

Answer (score 0):

It seems a vague way of saying 'fair policy', so not exactly wrong. (Fair trial might have the kids asking questions that the current Turkish regime might not be comfortable with.)

You might argue that 'fair laws' would be gramatically better, but [law](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/law) can be used as both a countable and uncountable noun.

Definition of law noun from the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary

1.(also the law) [uncountable] the whole system of rules that everyone in a country or society must obey
 *If they entered the building they would be breaking the law.* 
*In Sweden it is against the law to hit a child.
 Defence attorneys can use any means within the law to get their client off.
 British schools are now required by law to publish their exam results. 
The reforms have recently become law. Do not think you are above the law (= think that you cannot be punished by the law). the need for better law enforcement*

3.[countable] a rule that deals with a particular crime, agreement, etc.
 *law (against something)
 the 1996 law against the hiring of illegal immigrants
 law (on something) The government has introduced some tough new laws on food hygiene. 
strict gun laws
 a federal/state law
 to pass a law (= officially make it part of the system of laws)
 (informal) There ought to be a law against it!*

Comment: In this unit some texts tell the kids about children's rights. I guess the writers read about the children's rights on the Net and decided to call that right "fair law." On the net I've read this among the rights of children. You have the right to
legal help and fair
treatment in a justice
system that respects
your rights.
If the laws of your country provide better
protection of your rights than the articles in this
Convention, those laws should apply